showing a space is contractible using the homotopy extension property
Suppose that the pair $(Y,Z)$ satisfies the homotopy extension property with $Z\subseteq Y$ and suppose that the inclusion $\iota\colon Z\to Y$ is null homotopic. I want to prove or disprove that $Y$ is contractible.
My intuition says it is contractible! Since we can extend the null homotopy of $\iota$ to one of the identity map.
My attempt: $\iota\colon Z\to Y$ is null homotopic, thus there exists a continuous map $H_t\colon Z\to Y$ such that $H_0 = \iota$ and $H_1 = C$ where $C\colon Z\to Y$ is the constant map $C(z) = y_0$ for all $z\in Z$. Observe that $H_0 = \text{id}_Y\vert_Z$. By the homotopy extension property it follows that there exists a homotopy $G_t\colon Y\to Y$ such that $G_0 = \text{id}_Y$ and $G_t(z) = H_t(z)$ for all $z\in Z$. Thus $G_1(z) = y_0$ for all $z\in Z$. I get stuck here, I want to show that $G_1$ is the constant map for all $y\in Y$.
Any tips on how to do this would be greatly appreciated. I still don't know if what I am trying to prove is true. So a counter example is also welcome!

It is not true. Here is a counterexample.
Let $Y = S^1$ and $Z = \{*\}$ with $* \in S^1$. Then $\iota$ is null-homotopic, but $S^1$ is not contractible.
